# Android - Failure to launch an Activity via an Intent from a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I create a fresh project in Android studio using the wizard that creates a blank activity with a fragment. I then create a second basic activity with a fragment. In the first fragment I add a button, which has an OnClickListener, and inside of onClick() it does the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
getActivity().startService(intent);
```

When I click the button, despite the code being run, the activity is never launched. There are no errors in logcat. Because I did it with the wizard, the activity is automatically added to the manifest.

Comment: you need to right startActivity(intent) not service

Comment: are you wnat to start service or activity??

Answer (score 3):

Your code calls `startService()` but it should `startActivity()`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Oh gosh, that is embarrassing. Must be time for a break. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivity()` insteed of `startService()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```